# RuntimeError: abort(OOM). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info

Tags: ffmpeg, webassembly

I'm using ffmpeg.wasm 0.9.7 (at the time of this question).
Browser is Brave (Version 1.23.71 Chromium: 90.0.4430.72 (Official Build) (64-bit))

I get this error running an overlay ffmpeg command in the browser, slapping an png over an hevc mp4 4K video of size, almost 40 Megabyte.

`RuntimeError: abort(OOM). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.`

Here's my code in Angular. Stripped down for brevity

```
async generatePreviews(event: any) {

    if (!ffmpeg.isLoaded()) {
      await ffmpeg.load();
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < this.files.length; index++) {

      this.video = this.files[index];
      const file_name = this.video.name.split('.')[0] + '-preview.mp4';

      ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'tempLogo.png', await fetchFile(this.watermark));
      ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', 'tempVideo.mp4', await fetchFile(this.video));


      // working command in normal terminal
      // ffmpeg -i tempVideo.mp4 -i tempLogo.png -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" temp.mp4

      await ffmpeg.run(
        '-i',
        'tempVideo.mp4',
        '-i',
        'tempLogo.png',
        '-filter_complex',
        'overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2',
        'temp.mp4'
      );

      const data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'temp.mp4');

      var blob = new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' });
      saveAs(blob, file_name); // using filesaver.js to save the blob

    }
  }
}
```

In chrome, I read up to 2Gb of file is possible to convert. Not sure why the OOM issues. Any settings I need to set or changes I need to do?

Update (4/26/2021)

This [thread offered a solution](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/issues/136#issuecomment-812825994), by building the ffmpeg wasm with a few tweaks. I am able to build, but using the built files even causes the OOM faster than the npm built from the ffmpeg wasm repo.

Comment: In thread you mentioned it was change from 2GB memory limit into 200MB (and in the last entry proposal of revert back to 2GB). Currently Chrome supports up to 4GB (but you may initiate just 2GB) - try to add `-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1`.

Comment: If above will not help - try to identify what is root cause using `--memoryprofiler` see [Emcc](https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html.)